# CentOs 7 Php sudo yum install php-mysql error

Tags: centos, php

I'm trying to install php but I got an error on the CentOs7. When I'm typing the;

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

There is an error occurs

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1 day, 0:39:55 ago on Thu 16 Sep 2021 08:29:16 AM EDT.
No match for argument: php-mysql
Error: Unable to find a match: php-mysql
```

What should I do for the installation php

Comment: EL7: You can find 3rd party repo's for php-mysql at http://rpm.pbone.net/ ..... e.g. the remi.repo . .... Please tick Redhat EL 7 and CentOS 7 for the search.

Comment: Try `yum install php-mysqlnd`

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Vlad works

```
sudo yum install php-mysqlnd
```

mysqlnd means `Mysql Native Dtaver`, it is a drop-in replacement for the MySQL Client Library (libmysql) for the PHP.

> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

You can see that for older PHP there are both `php-mysql` and `php-mysql` but for some systems and newer PHP only `php-mysqlnd` is available.

https://pkgs.org/search/?q=php-mysql

https://pkgs.org/search/?q=php-mysqlnd

In Fedora/CentOS its make difference, but in Debian world only `php-mysql` is available and it is the same what `php-mysqlnd` in Centos.

You can see that `php-mysqlnd` for debian/ubuntu is virtual package of `php-mysql`
https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-mysqlnd

Generally, if there are two options you should choose native drivers.

https://serverfault.com/questions/400434/php-mysqlnd-or-php-mysql